# Error with a vpn client (PPTP protocole) over ssh

Tags: ssh, vpn, ip, pptp

I have some errors when I use PPTP over ssh :

```
sudo ssh -L 1723:127.0.0.1:1723 vpn-server@$192.168.1.1
```

*192.168.1.1 is the vpn server ip.*

When I start pppd (client) whith the following command :

```
sudo pppd call tun nomagic logfd 2 nodetach debug dump
```

tun is the pppd setting file with :

```
pty "pptp 127.0.0.1 --nolaunchpppd"
name myname
password mypassword
remotename myremotename
#require-mppe-128
refuse-eap
file /etc/ppp/options
ipparam vpn
```

The first time, I have this error in the server log message :

```
peer refused to authenticate : terminating link
```

When I restart pppd after this, I have this message in the client :

```
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
```

This message is repeated x times ...

My pptp server is working without ssh. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to have any success tunneling PPTP over SSH. PPTP uses both a TCP-based control channel (running on TCP port 1723) *and* the Generic Routing Encapsulation (GRE) protocol, which sits at the same layer in the TCP/IP stack as TCP. SSH doesn't have functionality to tunnel GRE (or any other arbitrary protocol-- just TCP).